# How to use python to simulate probability problems with factorial

Tags: python, runtime-error, simulation, probability, factorial

I want to simulate a probalility problem, But the code comes up RunTimeError

There are k people in a room. Assume each
person’s birthday is equally likely to be any of the 365 days of the year (we exclude
February 29), and that people’s birthdays are independent (we assume there are no
twins in the room). What is the probability that two or more people in the group
have the same birthday?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import factorial

N = 365
k = np.arange(1,41)

def fun(k):
    return 1 - factorial(N)/N**k/factorial(N-k)

plt.plot(k, fun(k))
```

I want to simulate the probablity problem sucessfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Calculating the Birthday Paradox in SciPy](https://dzone.com/articles/calculating-birthday-paradox-scipy) we are warned that moderately large values of N and k will cause the formula to overflow if implemented directly, thus causing a run time error for your function fun.  The trick is to use logarithms to avoid overflow or underflow.

SciPy doesn’t have a log factorial function, but does have a log gamma function, so we use that instead.

**Modified Code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from numpy.lib.scimath import log
from numpy import exp
from scipy.special import gammaln

def fun(k):
  # Use log of gamma for log of factorial 
  # then inverse log (i.e. exponentiate)
  return 1 - exp( gammaln(N+1) - gammaln(N-k+1) - k*log(N) )
  # replaces 1 - factorial(N)/N**k/factorial(N-k)
  
N = 365
k = np.arange(1, 41)

# Display
plt.plot(k, fun(k))
plt.show()
```

**Result**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your function is wrong. Please check section 2.1. of the following reference:

> [https://users.cs.utah.edu/~jeffp/teaching/cs5955/L2-StatisticalPrinciples.pdf](https://users.cs.utah.edu/%7Ejeffp/teaching/cs5955/L2-StatisticalPrinciples.pdf)

Then, adjust your function accordingly:

```
    def fun(k):
    return 1 - (1-1/N)**(k*(k-1)/2)
```

Plot:

```
    plt.plot(k, fun(k))
```

The result:

[image: probabilities]

Comment: Actually the posted function is correct.  In your reference in section 2.1 under *What are the problems with this?*, the formula with the product when expressed using factorials is the more accurate posted function.